# How do I get the Image element printed without displaying it on a Window?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `Page` that contains a `StackPanel` element that contains some UI elements like `TextBlock`, `Image`, etc. I tried to print the `StackPanel`, everything inside it is printed, except the `Image` element.

I wrote the print statement inside the `Page` constructor without displaying the page on a `Window`. I guess that the `Image` is not rendered.

My question is: how do I get the `Image` element printed without displaying it on a `Window`?

Here is my code:

```cs
public partial class InvoiceForm : Page
{
    FixedDocument fixedDoc = new FixedDocument();
    PrintDialog prtDialog = new PrintDialog();

    bool isPrinted = false;

    public InvoiceForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        string dateNow = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMM yyyy", new CultureInfo("id-ID"));
        HeaderDateNow.Text = DateInfoDateNow.Text = dateNow;
        Console.WriteLine(dateNow);

        string saved = XamlWriter.Save(ContainerStackPanel);
        StringReader sReader = new StringReader(saved);
        XmlReader xReader = XmlReader.Create(sReader);
        StackPanel containerStackPanelClone = (StackPanel)XamlReader.Load(xReader);

        FixedPage fixedPage = new FixedPage();
        PageContent pageContent = new PageContent();
        FixedDocument fixedDoc = new FixedDocument();

        fixedPage.Children.Add(containerStackPanelClone);
        fixedPage.Margin = new Thickness(62, 38, 25, 30);
        pageContent.Child = fixedPage;

        fixedDoc.DocumentPaginator.PageSize = new Size(GetPaperSize(PaperKind.A4).Width * 96, 
            GetPaperSize(PaperKind.A4).Height * 96);
        fixedDoc.Pages.Add(pageContent);

        ContainerStackPanel.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
        ContainerStackPanel.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(0, 0), ContainerStackPanel.DesiredSize));

        Console.WriteLine("ContainerStackPanel, Width: {0}  Height: {1}", ContainerStackPanel.ActualWidth, ContainerStackPanel.ActualHeight);
        Console.WriteLine("fixedDoc, Width: {0}  Height: {1}",
            fixedDoc.DocumentPaginator.PageSize.Width, fixedDoc.DocumentPaginator.PageSize.Height);

        // Print the document
        prtDialog.PrintDocument(fixedDoc.DocumentPaginator, "Test Print Form");
    }
}
```

Comment: Just set it `.Visible` state to `false`

Comment: Can you provide yor code?

Comment: @Sergio Do you mean visibility of a window? Sorry, I forgot to say that I don't want to create an instance of a `Window` to display the `Image` first.

Comment: Well, try to create an instance and check if it appear at least